# Using Moq, is it possible to setup mocked tables by type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, moq

I have the following code where I'm trying to setup the mocked table based on the data type passed to the MockDbSet method.

```
private Mock<DbContext> mockContext = new Mock<DbContext>();

public DbContext GetContext()
{
    return mockContext.Object;
}

public void MockDbSet<T>(params T[] sourceList) where T : class
{
    var queryable = sourceList.AsQueryable();

    var dbSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
    dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(queryable.Provider);
    dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(queryable.Expression);
    dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(queryable.ElementType);
    dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => queryable.GetEnumerator());

    mockContext.Setup(c => c.Set(typeof(T))).Returns(dbSet.Object);
}
```

I get the following error at the mockContext.Setup line (22):

```
System.NotSupportedException: Conversion between generic and non-generic DbSet objects is not supported for test doubles.
```

I've tried

```
mockContext.Setup(c => c.Set<T>()).Returns(dbSet.Object);
```

This does not throw the exception, but also does not setup any data.

Is it possible to setup tables this way?

Thanks

Comment: I think you're mocking too much details. You should be mocking a service instead (Repository maybe) that returns an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: What are ultimately trying to do. `mockContext.Setup(c => c.Set<T>()).Returns(dbSet.Object);` is how it is normally done. If you are trying to access/mock a table like `myDbContext.TableName` then you need to actually setup access to it.

Comment: I don't follow, I am mocking a repository. I was just trying to reduce the amount of setup overhead, but I actually think this won't work the way I intended.

Comment: @T27M If you're mocking a service class (eg EmployeeService), then you setup (`new Mock<EmployeeService>()` or `new Mock<Respository<Employee>>()`) as `emplyoeeServiceMock.Setup(e=> e.GetData()).Returns(myInMemoryListOfEmployees);` No need for all the implementation details of EF.

Comment: @Nkosi The usual way I've been using is `mockContext.Setup(c => c.SomeTable).Returns(mockSet.Objet)`, the way you suggest did not populate any mock data. I will look into it again.

Comment: @user3185569 Could you link to something that elaborates this? What is e.GetData()? I used the following resource to setup my testing [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: Can you maybe show the code (or the interface) you are actually trying to unit test here? It’s difficult to see what you are trying to test, so it’s difficult to say if you are attempting to mock the right thing.

Comment: If you have a repository. Mock at the repository level. For instance Mock<IOrderRepository> rather than attempting to mock the DBContext inside the repository. The repository functionality can be tested via integration tests. The repository itself should aim to be as lightweight as possible with the business logic predominantly in the service layer being tested. I've outlined my preferred repository pattern implementation /w EF here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/237374/to-repository-or-not-to-repository/351179#351179  but it applies to any repository pattern.

Comment: @StevePy Do you have any concrete examples of how you have used this way for testing?

Answer (score 2):

To outline mocking at the Repository level:

Given Service / Controller code that interacts with a Repostory through a contract interface:

```
public interface IOrderRepository
{
   IQueryable<Order> GetOrderById (int orderId);
   IQueryable<Order> GetOrdersForCustomer (int customerId);
}
```

This is the preferred repository pattern I use. Returning IQueryable means that my consumers can take advantage of deferred execution to decide how the details will be used, resulting in more efficient queries. (I.e. using .Select() to get the fields they want, doing .Count() or .Any(), .FirstOrDefault(), or .Skip().Take() etc.)

alternatively you might use generic repositories:

```
public interface IRepository<Order>
{
   Order GetOrderById (int orderId);
   ICollection<Order> GetOrdersForCustomer (int customerId);
}
```

The repository methods would contain minimal to no business logic. In my case the repository would only be concerted with:

- Authorization (retrieve data based on the current user / tenant)
- Active / Soft-Delete state. (retrieve "active" data in a soft-delete environment unless told otherwise.)
- Temporal state. (Retrieve "current" date unless told otherwise.)

All business logic should reside in your service classes or controllers, where it can be tested in isolation. To test the above 3 conditions (if applicable) I use integration tests. These conditions are very low-level checks and would *not* change on any regular basis.

Lets say the code under test is in a Controller.

```
public class OrderController : IOrderController
{
  private readonly IOrderRepository _repository = null;
  private readonly IUnitOfWorkFactory _uowFactory = null;

  public OrderController(IUnitOfWorkFactory uowFactory, IOrderRepository repository)
  {
    if (uowFactory == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("uowFactory");

    if (repository == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("repository");

    _uowFactory = uowFactory;
    _repository = repository;
  }

  public void SomeActionOnOrder(int orderId)
  {
    using (var unitOfWork = _uowFactory.Create())
    {
      var order = _repository.GetOrderById(orderId)
      // Here lies your validation checks that the order was found, 
      // business logic to do your behaviour.. This is the stuff you want to test..
      // ...

      unitOfWork.Commit();
    }
  }
}
```

Now when you go to test your controller...

```
[Test]
public void EnsureSomeActionOnOrderDoesIt()
{
   var uowMock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
   var uowFactoryMock = new Mock<IUnitOfWorkFactory>();
   var repositoryMock = new Mock<IOrderRepository>();
   var testOrderId = -1;
   var stubOrders = new [] { newOrder { /* populate expected data... */ } };

   uowMock.Setup(x=>x.Commit());
   uowFactoryMock.Setup(x=>x.Create()).Returns(uowMock.Object);
   repositoryMock.Setup(x=>x.GetOrderById(testOrderId)).Returns(stubOrders.AsQueryable());

   var testController = new OrderController(uowFactoryMock.Object, repositoryMock.Object);
   testController.SomeActionOnOrder(testOrderId);

   // Everything "touched" as expected? (did the code fetch the object? did it save the changes?)
   uowFactoryMock.VerifyAll();
   uowMock.VerifyAll();
   repositoryMock.VerifyAll();

   // Perform asserts on your stub order if SomeAction modified state as you expected.
}
```

Integration tests against an actual database would handle any logic that the repositories would be expected to cover.

The repository pattern I have above is the IQueryable flavour, alternatively if you return an entity, just return the "stubs" with a stub order and return it.

The mocking framework I use is Moq. The above code may not be fully syntactically correct, based solely on memory. :)

The goal of unit tests, as far as TDD/BDD go, is that these tests should be reliably repeatable, and fast to execute so that they can be run repeatedly and frequently as you are developing. Keeping repositories relatively thin, and not touching on the business logic decisions means that they can serve as a reliable cut-off point for unit tests to mock out. The repository's job is to return data, so by mocking at that point it means we can control the data we expect the code under test to work with. We can mock it to return objects, null, throw exceptions, whatever our test scenario expects our code under test to handle.

In the above example I also demonstrate the use of a basic Unit of Work pattern which wraps the DB Context. The implementation that I use for EF is Medhime's DB Context Scope Factory/Locator. Using the Unit of Work pattern we also have mocks that can verify that the code under test is (or is not) saving data for instance. The repository would need to have a link to a unit of work (initialized in a constructor, or "located" as-per the Mehdime pattern) but we don't care about that aspect when testing our services & controllers, the repository is merely mocked out and its purpose is to return and (optionally) create data.

I'll have my repositories serve as factories for entities (I.e. CreateOrder() with list of product details & quantities) to ensure that new entities are initialized with all expected referential links and required data rather than relying on calling code. That calling code would have to be littered with extra queries etc. to retrieve referential data for a new order, so instead I have it pass the view model data through to the Order Repository to resolve, wire-up, and return a valid new Order entity.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I will have to spend some time looking over and putting this into practice.

Answer (score 1):

In a recent project, I created an extension method of a `List<T>` (could be IEnumerable, or whatever).

```
public static Mock<DbSet<T>> MockList<T>(this List<T> list) where T: class 
        {
            var mockDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();

            var queryable = list.AsQueryable();

            mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(queryable.Provider);
            mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(queryable.Expression);
            mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(queryable.ElementType);
            mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(queryable.GetEnumerator());

            return mockDbSet;
        }
```

It is then quite simple to call.

```
var myData = new List<MyDataType> { new MyDataType(), new MyDataType(), ....};
var mockDb = new Mock<MyContext>();
mockDb.Setup(x => x.MyDatas).Returns(myData.MockList().Object);
```